serial disconnection while driving multiple solenoids
I cannot energize multiple solenoids for some reason but a single solenoid works, let me try to elaborate.
Here is the article that describes the details of the board that I am trying to replicate, it has all the details.
Briefly:
Using Teensy 3.5, the mainboard is powered with a 12 V, 60 W power adapter, related schematics:

I am using 5VDC latching solenoids with the code below, Solenoids have 2 states- 0 and 1. happy to provide more details.
The problem is that this can switch 3 solenoids in sequence, when I try to switch the 4th one, I get:

Closed serial port COM3 due to disconnection from the machine

The solenoids need to energize briefly before switching to either state (0 or 1), the error happens in only one direction when trying to switch to state 1, no errors when switching to state 0. The switching happens in 6 sequential steps in a loop (refer to the valve_switch function in the code below). Before the serial disconnect, the last step completed is step 2. Strangely, when I try to print inside step 3,
Serial.println(ValveTimer/1000);

then even the first step is not completed for the 4th solenoid. Reproduced this.
Tried:

swapping the teensy,
cooling the drivers with forced air,
putting a delay in each step.
disconnecting the valves, no error.
confirmed the switching physically for the first solenoids.

The problem is erratic, sometimes it is the 3rd valve, and sometimes I don't get an error in the serial monitor but the monitor freezes, and then I have to power off the board to reconnect. Trying to find an oscilloscope to see if there is a drop in either at teensy's legs or at the board.
Valves.cpp
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "TCA6416A.h"
#include "Valves.h"

/* Defined Constants */
#define SOL_EN1               A12
#define SOL_EN2               A13
#define VALVE_HOLD_TIME_MS    100  //the time the valves stay energized in msec

TCA6416A portExpander(HIGH); //I2C address => 0x21 

bool ENABLE_valve_switch = 0; 
int Switch_state = 0; 
uint16_t valve_state = 0;
uint16_t valve_mask = 0; 

/* Constructor */
Valves::Valves(){}

void Valves::initValves(){
  //initialize the enable pins of DRV8844
  pinMode(SOL_EN1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(SOL_EN2, OUTPUT);
  //force a delay to allow DRV8844 to disable outputs
  delay(15); 
  //initialize the TCA6416A Port Expander
  portExpander.begin(); 
  portExpander.pinMode_all(0xFFFF);               // Configure all pins as outputs  -inverted from datasheet
  portExpander.digitalWrite_all(0x0000);          // Set logic of all output ports low (note all ports should still be configured as inputs by default)
}

void Valves::valve_set_direct(byte H_valves, byte L_valves){
  valve_stateL = L_valves; 
  valve_stateH = H_valves; 
  //concatonate two bytes to unsigned 16-bit 
  valve_state = ((H_valves << 8) | L_valves);
  //Go switch the valves. 
  ENABLE_valve_switch = 1; //enable valve Switch mode
  Switch_state = 1;        //set the state sequence to start at 1 
  valve_switch();          //Call the function to switch valves. 
}

void Valves::valve_set_indirect(int valve_number, bool State){
  //indirect mode of operation 
  if (valve_number < 1 || valve_number > 4){
    Serial.println("Error 1-4 only");
    return; 
  }
  else{
    if(State == 0){// we need to AND with all 1s
      //create the mask
      valve_mask = 0xFFFF; 
      //se the mask bits to desired values
      bitClear(valve_mask, (valve_number-1)); 
      valve_state = valve_state & valve_mask; 

      //Go Switch the Valves
      ENABLE_valve_switch = 1; //enable valve Switch mode
      Switch_state = 1;        //set the state sequence to start at 1 
      valve_switch();          //Call the function to switch valves. 
    }
    else if (State == 1){ // we need to OR with all 0s
      //create the mask
      valve_mask = 0x0000; 
      //set the mask bits to desired values
      bitSet(valve_mask,(valve_number -1)); 
      valve_state = valve_state | valve_mask; 
      
      //Go Switch the Valves
      ENABLE_valve_switch = 1; //enable valve Switch mode
      Switch_state = 1;        //set the state sequence to start at 1 
      valve_switch();          //Call the function to switch valves.   
    }
  }  
}

void Valves::valve_switch(void){
  if(Switch_state == 1 && ENABLE_valve_switch == 1){
    //Serial.println("S1"); 
    Switch_state = 2; 
  }
  else if(Switch_state == 2){
    //Serial.println("S2"); 
    //write to the port expander the configured valve_state
    portExpander.digitalWrite_all(valve_state);
    //Serial.println("all valve_state written"); 
    //enable LOW outputs to set new state
    digitalWrite(SOL_EN1, HIGH);
    //Serial.println("valve_state written"); 
    Switch_state = 3; //go to next state   
    //Serial.println("next state is defined");  
    ValveTimer = 0;    //reset the timer
    //Serial.println("valve timer reset"); 
  }
  else if(Switch_state == 3){
    if(ValveTimer < VALVE_HOLD_TIME_MS){
      ; //hold the outputs for specified hold time
      //Serial.println(ValveTimer/1000); 
    }
    else{
      //Serial.println("S3"); 
      //disable LOW outputs to set latch valves
      digitalWrite(SOL_EN1, LOW);
      Switch_state = 4; //go to next state
    }
  }
  else if(Switch_state == 4){
    //Serial.println("S4"); 
    //write to the port expander the configured valve_state
    portExpander.digitalWrite_all(valve_state);
    //enable HIGH outputs to set new state
    digitalWrite(SOL_EN2, HIGH);
    ValveTimer = 0;    //reset the timer
    Switch_state = 5; //go to next state
  }
  else if(Switch_state == 5){
      if(ValveTimer < VALVE_HOLD_TIME_MS){
      ; //hold the outputs for specified hold time
      //Serial.println(ValveTimer/1000);
    }
    else{
      //Serial.println("S5"); 
      //disable HIGH outputs to set latch valves
      digitalWrite(SOL_EN2, LOW);
      Switch_state = 6; //go to next state
    }
  }
  else if(Switch_state == 6 ){
    //Serial.println("S6"); 
    valve_stateL = valve_state & 0xff; 
    valve_stateH = (valve_state >> 8); 
    Serial.print(F("valve changed: "));    
    Serial.print(valve_stateH,BIN);
    Serial.print("_"); 
    Serial.println(valve_stateL,BIN);
    Switch_state = 0; 
    ValveTimer = 0; 
    ENABLE_valve_switch = 0; //disable valve Switching mode
    return; 
  }
}


You need to show the schematics if you have any errors.

would be happy to show, what else is needed besides what I already shared? I can only think of the port expander.

Please provide a Vcc pin oscillogram when you are switching the relays.

will do it once I find an oscilloscope handy

The capacitor C21 at V3P3OUT should go to VNEG, not to LGND and should be 470 nF. Are C17 and C18 the only capacitors connected to the supply?

yes, that's a good one. and yes, they are the only ones connected to the supply. I think C18 should be 10 uF too. These could be the root causes of the problem I guess.
